# pandoc latex to rtf - No link colors

Tags: hyperref, conversion, pandoc, pandoc-citeproc

I am trying to convert a document from latex to rtf using pandoc.
The conversion works fine, except for the colors of the citations.
The usual latex pipeline produces the expected result:

[image]

But the .rtf file does not (not colored, plus other differences I already know how to fix):

[image]

This is the .tex file:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=red]{hyperref} 

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
Citation \cite{test}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{test.bib}

\end{document}
```

The command I used:
`pandoc test.tex -f latex -s -o test.rtf --bibliography test.bib`

I know there are some options to pass variables to the command (e.g. `-V citecolor=red`). I tried several (I would say all the simplest) approaches...
I feel I am missing something big here - or pandoc is actually not able to manage this correctly.

Thanks to all!

---

pandoc 1.19.2.1
texlive 2019

gentoo

Comment: Pandoc's AST does not represent color attributes. Your best shot would be a filter: https://pandoc.org/filters.html

Comment: Your pandoc version is a bit old (1.19.2.1 is from January 2017, current is 2.9.2.1, see https://pandoc.org/releases.html). Probably unrelated to your current problem, but you could upgrade to avoid potential other issues.